# Postgres full text search: how to search multiple words in multiple fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing, full-text-search

i'm using for the first time Postgresql and i'm trying to create a search engine in my website. i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  description TEXT,
  address TEXT NOT NULL,
  city TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Then i created an index for every field of the table (is this the right way? Or maybe i can create one index for all fields?):

```
CREATE INDEX shop_name_fts ON shop USING gin(to_tsvector('italian', name));
CREATE INDEX shop_desc_fts ON shop USING gin(to_tsvector('italian', description));
CREATE INDEX shop_addr_fts ON shop USING gin(to_tsvector('italian', address));
CREATE INDEX shop_city_fts ON shop USING gin(to_tsvector('italian', city));
```

Now, what is the SQL query if i want to search one word in every index?

I tried this and it works:

```
SELECT id FROM shop WHERE to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('$word') OR
                          to_tsvector(description) @@ to_tsquery('$word') OR 
                          to_tsvector(address) @@ to_tsquery('$word') OR 
                          to_tsvector(city) @@ to_tsquery('$word')
```

Does exist a better way to do the same?
Can i search `to_tsquery` into multiple `to_tsvector`?
A friend of mine suggests a solution, but it is for MySQL database:

```
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE MATCH(name, description, address, city) AGAINST('$word')
```

What is the solution for Postgresql?

In addition, can i search multiple `to_tsquery` into multiple `to_tsvector`? what is the SQL query if i want to search two words or more than one word? Can i just pass "two words" to $word from PHP? If i can, how does it work? Does it search for first word AND second one or first word OR second one?

Comment: Why do you even want to do a full text search on a name or a city ? You should probably do much simpler comparisons on those fields.

Comment: These are sample data. My database contains shops data, that the name could me "The great restaurant". I'm going to edit my question, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like what you want is, in fact to search the concatenation of all those fields.

You could build a query doing exactly this

```
... where to_tsvector('italian', name||' '||coalesce(decription,'')...) @@ to_tsquery('$word')
```

and build an index on the exact same computation:

```
create index your_index on shop
using GIN(to_tsvector('italian',name||' '||coalesce(decription,'')...))
```

Don't forget to use `coalesce` on columns accepting NULL values.

Comment: It sounds good, but i get this erro: `ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Comment: I solved with this: `create index shop_fts on shop using GIN(to_tsvector('italian', name || ' ' || description || ' ' || address || ' ' || city));`

Comment: So now, how to search for multiple words? And how does it work?

Comment: Use the exact same phrasing in the index and in the where part.

Comment: I add `coalesce` to my previous `create index` query. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Now, if you tell me how to search for multiple words and how to use AND and OR with them... i can click to accept your answer :)

Comment: For multiple words search, use the syntax of `to_tsquery` with operators `&`, `|` and `!`: `to_tsquery('molto & facile' )`. More details here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-intro.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to search for a word except another word? I'm trying to write `word1 !word2` but it gives me error. It works only if i use `word1&!word2`... is that right?