# How to do text search in postgresql with multiple results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Let's say I get the following table when I do
`select name, alternative_name from persons;`

```
          name            |           alternative_name
--------------------------+----------------------------------
 Johnny A                 | John the first
 Johnny B                 | The second John
```

Now with this query
`select name from persons where to_tsvector(name || alternative_name) @@ to_tsquery('John');`:

```
          name            |           alternative_name
--------------------------+----------------------------------
 Johnny A                 | John the first
```

Shouldn't I get both? How can I do a full text search on both the `name` and `columns` where I get all rows that match the search query?

Edit: Yes, there is indeed a typo here. It is `to_tsquery`

Comment: Don't you want to use  `to_tsquery` instead of `to_query` ? And you really should add a space so that you don't miss words because of concatenation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres full text search: how to search multiple words in multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662755/postgres-full-text-search-how-to-search-multiple-words-in-multiple-fields)

Comment: @DenysSéguret : Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you concat without space:

```
t=# with c(n,a) as (values('Johnny A','John the first'),('Johny B','The second John'))
select * from c
where to_tsvector(n || a) @@ to_tsquery('John')
;
    n    |        a
---------+-----------------
 Johny B | The second John
(1 row)
```

so first haystack becomes `Johnny AJohn the first`, thus lexeme do not match, try:

```
t=# with c(n,a) as (values('Johnny A','John the first'),('Johny B','The second John'))
select * from c
where to_tsvector(n ||' '|| a) @@ to_tsquery('John')
;
    n     |        a
----------+-----------------
 Johnny A | John the first
 Johny B  | The second John
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I mentioned that in comment but that's obviously not the problem according to the results OP is displaying (assuming that's the real data, query and results).

Comment: @DenysSéguret yes - he has the "opposite result" - but I assumed his code is not copy paste after seeing `to_query`. Fair point though - I should have make clear it before answering.

Comment: @DenysSéguret : and you are correct in assuming that this is not real data.